# Increase amount of PHP processes executed by Apache from the same client

Tags: apache-2.4, php7

We have an apache server setup with PHP 7.1 on it.

It's sole job is to receive and process requests from another server that is sending XML files for processing. This server can send upwards of 20 XML's per second in parallel.

However our receiving server with the PHP script only handles 10 at a time, even though we can see 20 Apache Processes running on the linux box.

We see the Apache access log showing receipt of the first 20 XML's when they begin arriving, but then it only handles 10 at a time, with the other 10 just waiting around to be executed.

Is there some sort of limit of the number of PHP scripts that can be run by the same client? Or some other limitation in Apache restricting the other remaining processes?

The Apache config is the default config from a SLES 12 SP3 after installing Apache.

Comment: Dump mpm_prefork and use mpm_event (or nginx) with php-fpm. This is always step 1 for apache/PHP performance issues.

Comment: Ok will have a look at that